# SQL column exist and not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my DB test, I have 400 tables.I would like to know in what table the column ID exists and in which tables the column ID does not exist. (see the pic)

[image]

I tryed with this query, but doesn't work. What's the best way ?

```
 SELECT COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME, 'Yes' As MyCol_ID
 FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COLUMNS,
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES TABLES
 WHERE  COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME
   AND Upper(COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME) = Upper('ID') 
   AND  TABLES.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
   order by COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME

 UNION 

SELECT COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME, 'No' As MyCol_ID
 FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COLUMNS,
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES TABLES
 WHERE  COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = TABLES.TABLE_NAME
   AND Upper(COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME) <> Upper('ID') 
   AND  TABLES.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
   order by COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using the `sys.` variants.  Run this in the context of your test DB:

```
SELECT T.NAME, CASE WHEN C.NAME = 'my_ColID' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
FROM SYS.TABLES T
LEFT JOIN SYS.COLUMNS C ON C.object_id = T.object_id 
                       AND C.NAME = 'my_ColID'
ORDER BY T.NAME
```

Comment: Thank you !! ;-) Your query is ok.

Answer (score 2):

One method is basically a `left join`:

```
select t.table_schema, t.table_name,
       (case when c.column_name is null then 'no' else 'yes' end) as id_exists
from information_schema.tables t left join
     information_schema.columns c
     on t.table_name = c.table_name and t.table_schema = c.table_schema and
        c.column_name = 'ID' 
where t.table_type = 'BASE_TABLE';
```

Notice that I fixed the join to include the schema name as well as the table name.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this query does not return any value, but Aaron's ok.